# Tabs hides content at bottom in Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have tabs in my ionic project but when I scroll to the bottom of content tabs hides the bottom part as it's behind the tabs.

Any ideas resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic set height of content div dynamically. So somehow it's not calculating required height of ion-content.

That happens when your content have floating element(float left/right).

You can set `clear: both; display: block` to wrapping element